# How Do I Determine If The 5 Numbers I Typed Into An Array Are Sequential using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to write a really simple poker game.  I'm just using the non-face cards, 2-9, without suites or anything of the like.  I'm trying to figure out how to write a method that determines if five cards are a full house, which is a pair and a 3 of a kind.  I have the user input 5 integers that represent card values and store them in a single array.  I tried writing something like this:

```
public static boolean containsFullHouse(int[] hand)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
         int count = 0;

         for (int j = 0; j < hand.length; j++){
              if (hand[i] == hand[j]){
                 count++;}

              if (count == 3){
                 return true;}
         }
     }
         for(int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
              for(int j = i + 1; j < hand.length; j++){ 
                  if(hand[i] == hand[j]){
                        return true;}
                   }
               }
         }  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The test would be if any two of them are NOT sequential.

Comment: perfect candidate for unit testing if you aren't already...

Answer (score 2):

You need to count the occurrences of each number, and create what is called a cardinality map.  Then the cardinalities must be (2,3) or (3,2).  If not using guava or Apache Commons Collections (which contain convenience methods to do this), this can be done in the following way:

```
public static boolean isFullHouse(final int[] input) {
    if (input.length != 5) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("need 5 integers"); }
    Map<Integer, Integer> cardinalityMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : input) {
        if (cardinalityMap.containsKey(i)) {
            cardinalityMap.put(i, cardinalityMap.get(i) + 1);
        }
        else {
            cardinalityMap.put(i, 1);
        }
    }

    if (cardinalityMap.size() != 2) { return false; }
    Collection<Integer> occurences = cardinalityMap.values();
    int first = occurences.iterator().next();
    return first == 2 || first == 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

- You're checking index `i` twice, although correct (since you check for `count == 3`), it's unnecessary.
- You're also returning before you check the other 2.
- The second loop will return true since it will find the numbers from the previous loop.

If you sort them, you can simply check whether the two pairs of cards on both sides are the same and check whether the middle card is the same as either one. So something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(hand);
return (hand[0] == hand[1] && hand[3] == hand[4] &&
        (hand[2] == hand[1] || hand[2] == hand[3]));
```

**Alternatively, if you want to fix your function:**

```
public static boolean containsFullHouse(int[] hand)
{
     // a variable that keeps track of one of the 3-of-a-kind indices (used in 2-of-a-kind check)
     int pos = -1;

     for (int i = 0; i < hand.length && pos == -1; i++){
         // start count at one instead
         int count = 1;

         // start j from next position rather than 0
         for (int j = i+1; j < hand.length && pos == -1; j++){
              if (hand[i] == hand[j]) {
                 count++;
              }

              if (count == 3) {
                 pos = i;
              }
         }
     }

     // if we didn't find 3-of-a-kind, return false
     if (pos == -1)
         return false;

     // look for 2-of-a-kind
     for(int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
         // exclude elements that match one of the 3-of-a-kind
         if (hand[i] != hand[pos]){
             for(int j = i + 1; j < hand.length; j++){ 
                 if(hand[i] == hand[j]){
                        return true;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Clever solution.  The answers using a cardinality map are more general but less efficient/concise.

Comment: This is perfect.  I'm trying not to get too far ahead of the class.  I just wanted to fix my function and I also wanted to see how far off I was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap from Apache Commons to do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] fullHouse = new Integer[]{7, 7, 7, 4, 4};
    Integer[] notFullHouse = new Integer[]{2, 2, 2, 2, 3};
    Integer[] notFullHouse2 = new Integer[]{1, 4, 2, 2, 3};

    System.out.println(isFullHouse(fullHouse));
    System.out.println(isFullHouse(notFullHouse));
    System.out.println(isFullHouse(notFullHouse2));

}

private static boolean isFullHouse(Integer[] cards){
    Map<Integer,Integer> cardinalityMap = CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap(Arrays.asList(cards));

    if(cardinalityMap.size() == 2) {
        if (cardinalityMap.values().containsAll(Arrays.asList(2, 3))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: See my answer for a similar method without using an external library.

Comment: +1 Sensible approach - if you have 2 of "something" and 3 of "something else", this must be a full house - otherwise, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

A full house consists of 2 different integers, so keep a counter for both. It also needs to keep track of the 2 different values. If you combine this you get something like this:

```
public static boolean containsFullHouse(int[] hand)
{
    int value1 = -1, count1 = 0;
    int value2 = -1, count2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        if(hand[i] == value1) {
            // Found another value1 card
            count1++;
        } else if(hand[i] == value2) {
            // Found another value2 card
            count2++;
        } else if(value1 == -1) {
            // Found a new card, store as value1
            value1 = hand[i];
            count1++;
        } else if(value2 == -1) {
            // Found a new card, store as value2
            value2 = hand[i];
            count2++;
        } else {
            // Found a third card, so it cannot be a full house!
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(value2 == -1) {
        // Found 'five of a kind'?!
        return false;
    }

     // Check if it is a full house
    return (count1 == 3 && count2 == 2) || (count1 == 2 && count2 == 3;)
}
```